# Filter some questions in the existing questions

Tags: macros

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exam}
\def\choice{....????} %Help me define the \ choice command and ex enviroment
    \begin{document}
    
   \begin{ex}
    A question 
    \end{ex}
    \begin{ex}
    A question 
    \end{ex}
    \begin{ex}
    A question 
    \end{ex}
    \begin{ex}
    A question 
    \end{ex}
    \begin{ex}
    A question 
    \end{ex}
    \begin{ex}
    A question 
    \end{ex}
    \begin{ex}
    A question 
    \end{ex}
    \begin{ex}
    A question 
    \end{ex}
    \begin{ex}
    A question 
    \end{ex}
    \begin{ex}
    A question 
    \end{ex}
    \choice{5}%When executing this command, the first 5 questions will be compiled and displayed on the pdf file
    \end{document}
```

After compiling, you will get a Pdf file containing the first 5 questions

```
Exam1. 
A question
Exam2. 
A question
Exam3. 
A question
Exam4. 
A question
Exam5. 
A question
```

You can use any necessary package for example: environ,...

Comment: Outline of how I might do it: Copy ex-environment to environment excopy. Redefine ex-environment to step a counter and to define a macro from its body whose macro-name contains the value of the counter. The redefined ex-environment could create the definition-text of the macro as follows: Read the body in verbatim-catcode-régime and wrap it into `\scantokens` and an `excopy`-environment. The `\choice`-comand could use its argument for doing a sequence of  `\csname..\endcsname`-calls for calling the macros whose names contain the counter-values, e.g., depending on whatsoever `\ifnum`-condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `environ` package, similar to what was proposed in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/181178/118712

Essentially you replace the content of the specified environment with an empty `{}`. You will have to specifiy the `\if` condition command before every `ex` environment. You could try to add it to your environment definition using `newenvironment`, I guess. You can streamline this a bit using a the theorms counter `\theex`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{environ}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exam}
\makeatletter
\providecommand{\env@ex@save@env}{}
\providecommand{\env@ex@process}{}
\makeatother

\def\cond{3}
\newcommand{\condition}{\ifnum\cond=\theex\RenewEnviron{ex}[1]{}\fi}

\begin{document}
    \condition
    \begin{ex}
        \item item
    \end{ex}

    \condition
    \begin{ex}
        \item another item
    \end{ex}

    \condition
    \begin{ex}
        \item another item
    \end{ex}
    
    \condition
    \begin{ex}
        \item another item
    \end{ex}

    \condition
    \begin{ex}
        \item another item
    \end{ex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Theoretically, it should be possible to add the `\condition` command to a `\newenvironment`, so that you do not have to put it there manually every time, but I could not get that to work. I'd appreciate pointers though, because I'm intrigued to understand why it is not working, now.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: But I want the structure to be the same as mine, i.e. no \codition command before \begin{ex},....